# Load seed data from YML to db with one-to-many relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new in Rails, and I got a problem. What is the best way to load data from YML file like this:

```
   projects:
 - title: 'family'
   todos:
    - text: 'Get some milk'
      isCompleted: false
    - text: 'Cook some bacon'
      isCompleted: true
    - text: 'Repair the front door'
      isCompleted: false
 - title: 'work'
   todos:
    - text: 'Call my boss'
      isCompleted: true
    - text: 'Finish my work tasks'
      isCompleted: true
    - text: 'Get fired'
      isCompleted: false
 - title: 'therest'
   todos:
    - text: 'Do something'
      isCompleted: false
    - text: 'Ask a question on stackoverflow'
      isCompleted: false
```

So, I have two models - todo model (text and isCompleted fields) and project model (only title field). Project has_many todos. 
I tried to do it like this:

```
seed_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds', 'seeds.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
Project.create!(config)
```

But I've got an error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'projects' for Project.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I think you have a copy-and-paste error in your YAML, yes? That's not valid syntax, I think.

Comment: Do you mean this '-' symbols? Yeah, they seem completely wrong here. But now I get another error - 
`Psych::SyntaxError: (/Users/Aldres/Desktop/tasktracker/db/seeds/seeds.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 3
/Users/Aldres/Desktop/tasktracker/db/seeds.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'`

Comment: I was thinking that your indentation seems wrong. I don't know why `projects` is indented as you have in your post. And, if each of those things under `projects` is a `project`, then it would seem that you need to iterate the `config` var to create your `Projects`.

Comment: Something like:
`config.each do |key, value|`?
Still can't figure it out

Comment: Yes, something like that. Although, you would have to examine the structure of `config` to get the syntax right. It might be something like `config[:projects].each do |project|`. You can add `config` to your OP if you need more guidance.

Comment: Looks like, that
`config[:projects],each do |proj|
  Project.create(proj)
end
`
Would do the trick, but it doesn't in fact

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174975/discussion-between-jvillian-and-aldres).

Comment: On a tangent: IMO, the seeds file is for loading data that your application requires to run _not_ pre-loading general data. Consider putting this yaml in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in chat, you'll need to use something like:

```
config[:projects].each do |project|
  todos = project[:todos]
  project.delete(:todos)
  new_project = Project.create(project)
  todos.each do |todo|
    new_project.todos.create(todo)
  end
end
```

That assumes your YML is formatted correctly.

Comment: There is no need to iterate over the projects OR the todos, much less both. @robertoplancarte's answer is better

Comment: There is no need to iterate in *any* circumstance? Or in *certain* circumstances? If the latter, then under *what* circumstances is iteration not needed?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos
end

Project.create!(title: 'family', 
                todos_attributes:[{text:'1',isCompleted:false}, 
                                 {text:'2',isCompleted:false},...])
```

If you *have* to use YAML you will have to read the YAML then turn it into something rails can create entities from. Put this in your seeds file:

`yaml_hash = YAML.load(File.read('db/your_yaml.yaml'))`

`rails_arr_of_hashes = yaml_hash['projects'].map{|p| {title: p['title'], todos_attributes: p['todos'] }`

`Project.create(rails_arr_of_hashes)`

put your YAML into db/your_yaml.yaml and then run

`rails db:seed`

Remember to add the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos` into the Project model.

Good luck learning Rails :)

Comment: Problem is, that I have to use YAML. And I can't figure out, how should I read and transform this file into entities.

Comment: that should work if you keep you YAML structure as it is in your question... just indented correctly

Comment: Looks logical. But now there's something with types.
`TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
/Users/Aldres/Desktop/tasktracker/db/seeds.rb:10:in `[]'
/Users/Aldres/Desktop/tasktracker/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
`
Line 10 is 
`rails_arr_of_hashes = yaml_hash['projects'].map{|p| {title: p['title'], todos_attributes: p['todos'] }}`

Comment: Ah, my bad. A bit of misspelling in my YML file. Now everything is okay. Thank you :)

Comment: If you can't change the name of the `todos` key in the yaml file, you could use gsub to change it to `todos_attributes` _before_ loading the file as YAML instead of iterating over the hash _after_. `YAML.load(File.read('projects.yml').gsub(/\:todos\:/, ':todos_attributes:'))`